# Can't mount USB drive (DROBO)

Tags: usb, mount, hard-drive

I'm trying to mount a USB Drobo drive array.  This worked great under 16.04 but then I upgraded to 17.04 and now it doesn't show up.  The drive is formatted for NTFS and I have the latest NTFS packages installed for read and write.  If I do

```
lsusb
```

I see "Data Robotics" so the system sees it but it never shows up in the File Explorer.

Here's relevant dmesg output

```
[    4.162459] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TRUSTED  Mass Storage     2.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    4.162788] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[    4.163335] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[    4.163706] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 34359738368 512-byte logical blocks: (17.6 TB/16.0 TiB)
[    4.164680] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[    4.164682] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[    4.165850] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[    4.165855] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    4.166560] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[    4.182666]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
```

Also, with the drive currently disconnected I still have sdb, sdb1 and sdb2 in /dev so should I perhaps try to remove those first?

OTHER INFO: If I plug the drive into my mac it shows up and mounts fine so I know that the drive is working properly.

Comment: LOL!  I love that "Very Big Device" line ha ha ha

Comment: I can't really answer this but there is an article here  : http://krook.net/archives/217 but he installed on CentOS. Hope it may help. also here: http://www.drobospace.com/forums/showthread.php?tid=387